# MacTex Upgrade from 2015 to 2016

Tags: latex

I wish to migrate from using MacTex 2015 to MacTex 2016 on my Mac. I have Sierra installed on my Laptop. I wish to know if:

1. Installing MacTex will overwrite my old MacTex or retain it (I
   actually want it overwritten!)?
2. If it does not overwrite, then what measures should be taken to completely remove the older version and switch to the 2016
   version?

I am asking these questions since the explanation provided on www.tug.org/mactex is not sufficiently clear, and it add more to the confusion.

Comment: You are running Sierra, I assume?

Answer (score 1):

Installing MacTeX 2016 will create a new `2016` directory in `/usr/local/texlive/` with all of TeX and friends in it. It will also update all symlinks etc. to point to the new versions. So you can run `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/texlive/2015` afterwards to remove the old version. This will lead to some broken links in `/Library/TeX` but I never bothered with cleaning them up and they won't be used anyway.

Comment: The above answer is correct.  I have both 2014 and 2015 MacTex installed on my computer.  Eventually, I will delete the 2014 version.